# Assault on the ivory tower

Tags: meaning

In the following sentence from a programming book, what does the "launch one final assault on the ivory tower" mean (bolded by me)?

> I'll take a fairly opinionated view of what the role of an architect
>   is, and hopefully **launch one final assault on the ivory tower**.

This is the close of the first paragraph of a chapter in the book, to start explanation from the next paragraph.

I believe "ivory tower" is a religious word describing "purity". This could also mean that "ideal but not practical".
And I think "assault" means the attack to it.

So my current interpretation of the sentence is:

"I'll describe my opinion on that, and it's practical contrast to other words from others which are ideal but not practical"

And I think, by putting "one final", he'll trying to express his description could destroy the purity at all.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Could you please edit your question to include what you found in the dictionary and why it didn't help?

Comment: You should include more research and context in your question. But 'Ivory Tower' is used in English to refer to intellectual concerns that don't take into account physical concerns and realities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivory_tower

Comment: Sure. I'm thinking if I should simplify the question (so that others can get to the point fast), or better to put my finding so far.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  In a literal sense, it would most likely refer to undertaking a military attack on a white tower, or even a tower made out of elephant tusks, although that seems unlikely.  In a figurative sense, it most likely refers to denigrating someone with either a self-righteous or a puritanical nature.  However, it could mean neither of these.  What it actually means in context requires said context to be understood.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman your latter one sounds the meaning of the sentence in this context.

Comment: You believe that _ivory tower_ is a religious word describing "purity." That's a decent initial guess, but that's [not what it means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ivory%20tower).

Comment: @J.R. Would you mind explaining it more? I see the words are described as "In the Judeo/Christian tradition, the term ivory tower is used as a symbol for noble purity. It originates with the Song of Solomon .." in [Ivory tower (Wikipedia)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ivory_tower). So I think _ivory tower_ is religious words which could describe "purity".

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but I will say this: just because a phrase has religious origins doesn't mean it's still used in religious contexts. Nowadays, I usually see _ivory tower_ as referring to the high thinkers in academia. But I'm starting to wonder if you maybe should have asked this on [ell.se] – read [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell/3723#3723) if you're falriy new to the two sites.

Answer (score 5):

In standard modern usage, *ivory tower* is no longer a religious reference, it has become desanctified into a stock idiom meaning a group of intellectuals and/or aesthetes isolated from the mundane world.  The image is of a pristine building towering over a city --and entirely disconnected from it.  It most typically, but not exclusively, refers to the academic world --colleges and universities, particularly ones that are more prestigious.  An assault on the ivory tower is an attempt to break through the supposed "groupthink" of such a group, and to force the realities of every day life into their perceptions.

In this case, the most likely meaning is that (he feels) there is an unrealistic conception of the term "architect" promoted by an influential group isolated from the realities of actual practice, and his next chapter will be an attempt to counter this.

(Incidentally, the metaphor of assaulting the ivory tower was reified in Michael Ende's *The Neverending Story*, in a scene where the residents of the nation of Fantasia attempt to force contact with their remote and godlike ruler through destroying her isolated residence, a literal ivory tower that is also called "The Ivory Tower.")

Answer (score 1):

This phrase has been used a few times recently.

- [Assault on the Ivory Tower](http://www.spectator.co.uk/2012/12/assault-on-the-ivory-tower/), The Spectator, February 2012
- [The Next Assault on the Ivory Tower: Unbundling the College Degree](http://www.forbes.com/sites/schoolboard/2015/03/23/the-next-assault-on-the-ivory-tower-unbundling-the-college-degree/), Forbes, March 2015
- [Rick Perry wages an assault on the ivory tower](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/rick-perry-wages-an-assault-on-the-ivory-tower/2011/07/26/gIQAyfrvsI_story.html), Washington Post, August 3, 2011

The "ivory tower" seen in these and several other articles refers to the higher education system. An assault on this system is usually debunking some sort of myth associated with this system that is supposed to be engaged in pure learning away from other distractions.

How is it being used?

- The professors are no longer being selected from the same pool that they were. Famous people are now competing for these positions, which is bad news for academics in the field who are already in high competition for them.
- The college degree awarded by higher education isn't all it's cracked up to be. A bachelor's degree doesn't give you an edge anymore, nor does it necessarily mean you'll be able to make enough to retire.
- The higher education system is being bogged down by financial concerns. They have to start acting like businesses and culling dead weight in order to continue operation.
- The higher education system is no longer a safe refuge. It is rife with crime, even sexual assault.

As it applies to your own example, the role of an architect in reality isn't the same as the role of an architect perceived by one pursuing a degree.